# dynamic text like dynamic header in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, dynamic, header

I am using dynamic header images with the following plugin which changes the heading images of all inside pages.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-headers/

But I did not get any plugin like it which will also change the heading text like it. Can any one suggest me what should be my procedure and how to implement dynamic text with an admin panel behind like nicasio dynamic header.

Comment: A fairly easy solution would be to use a custom field and then add a bit of code to your theme's `header.php` file. It's not really clear to which heading text you want to change, but this should work. Still if you add a link to what you mean, or update your question that might help.

Comment: It will be static isn't it. Not dynamic

Comment: If you use custom fields, it will be dynamic. Custom fields basically store additional information about posts in the database. You can use the built-in Custom Fields functionality and it will do trick for you.